# Cusp forms of weight 2 and level $\Gamma_0(p)$ where $p < 11$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Using Hida theory, we can prove that there is a cusp form of weight 2 and level $\Gamma_0(11)$. Are there ways to prove that there is no cusp forms of weight 2 and level $\Gamma_0(p)$ where $p < 11$?

**Edit.** As suggested by Jakob (*see comments*), calculating the dimension of $M_2 (\Gamma_0(p))$ is one way to prove the fact. But I am interested in proving it using congruences like Hida theory.

Comment: The space $M_2(\Gamma_0(p))$ just doesn't have very large dimension. See e.g. [this](https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/weight_two.html) and [this](https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/dimension_formulas.html) (and I'm sure many other places, these are just what appeared on quick Googling).

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Is there a reason you think there should be?  Proving existence is very different than proving nonexistence.

Comment: Also, how does the Hida theory proof work for level 11?

Comment: @Kimball Using Hida theory, the proof goes like the following: There is a cusp form $\Delta$ (*Ramanujan's delta*) of level $1$ and weight $12$. So, if we take a $11$-stabilization of it, there is a Hida family passing through it. At weight $2$ specialisation there should a cusp form of level $11$ with trivial nebentypus. But I do not know whether there should be an argument for $p < 11$ or not.

Comment: The issue is that proof uses the existence of a cusp form to construct a family.  It's translating one existence result into another.  For non-existence you'd need something like, if there were a weight 2 cusp form of level 5, say, you'd get some other cusp form.  And then you need to prove that doesn't exist (probably using something like dimension formulas).

Comment: @Offlaw The argument you give obviously works backwards as well, doesn't it? It establishes a bijection between cusp forms of weight 2 and level p, and p-ordinary cusp forms of weight (p+1) and level 1. If p < 11 there are none of the latter.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler The procedure used can show that there is an injection from the space of $p$-ordinary cusp forms of weight $p+1$ and level $1$ to the space of $p$-ordinary cusp forms of weight $2$ and level $\Gamma_0(p)$. But I'm struggling to show the surjection. I can't show that the $(p+1)$-specialization of the Hida family is an oldform.

Comment: A $p$-new eigenform of weight $k$ and level $\Gamma_0(p)$ always has Hecke eigenvalue $\pm p^{(k-2)/2}$. So if the weight is $> 2$ it cannot be ordinary

Answer (score 2):

The dimension of $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ is the genus of the Riemann surface $\Gamma_0(N)\backslash\mathfrak{H}^*$. See Theorem 2.24 in Shimura: Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic forms. The genus can be calculated via the Hurwitz formula applied to the branched cover $\Gamma_0(N)\backslash\mathfrak{H}^*\to\Gamma_0(1)\backslash\mathfrak{H}^*$. See Propositions 1.40 and 1.43 in the same book for explicit formulae.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention that I'm aware of the result via dimension calculation. My motivation of this question to reach some kind of contradiction using congruences of modular forms.

Comment: @Offlaw I see. It is a different question then. I leave my answer as non-experts might find it useful.